# Update the value of a variable from a YAML template

Tags: bash, azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a yaml file in my root directory called `versions.yml` that looks like:

```
variables:
  dev: 0.0.0
```

I am calling this from the Azure DevOps pipeline to first use the current value then update it with a new version.

azure-pipeline.yml

```
variables:
  - name: "Component"
    value: "azure-pipelines.yml"
  - template: versions.yml
  ...
    - bash: |
       "##vso[task.setvariable variable=${{ variables.dev }}]0.0.1"
```

I was attempting to follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax) example however, it never actually updates the value. If I run `echo ${{ variables.dev }}` it returns the original value of `0.0.0`. Is it possible tp update template variables with this syntax or is there a different way?

Comment: Rather than rolling your own semantic versioning implementation, consider using a semantic versioning tool like GitVersion to handle it for you.

Comment: @DanielMann It's less about the version itself and more about just being able to store variables in a template, reference them and be able to update them.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample, you need to pay attention to the following points:

1. The `${{ variables.dev }}` is template expression. So it will directly use the value in the template. So when you use bash script to update the variable , you need to use the `$(dev)` to get the value.
2. The value of `${{ variables.dev }}` is 0.0.0 instead of the variable name dev.

So you could use this to set the variable name in bash task.

You could directly set the variable name to dev in the bash task.

For example: `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=dev;]0.0.1`

Please refer to my sample:

```
variables:
- template: variable.yml  # Template reference

steps:
- script: echo  ${{ variables.dev }} 
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=dev;]0.0.1"'

- script: echo $(dev)
```

**Result:**

[image]